# SignalR Send Message to all Clients in the group Except few Clients

Tags: .net-core, signalr, signalr-hub, asp.net-core-signalr

I am using SignalR DotNetCore, I have created group, I need to send a message to all clients in group Except the specific clients with Connection Id.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/hubs?view=aspnetcore-2.2#the-clients-object), your are looking for GroupExcept which calls a method on all connections in the specified group, except the specified connections.

Comment: Please explain the down vote. The documentation is clear. If the source documentation is wrong then that's an issue with the source site.

Comment: You should explain what has to be done to answer the question, not simply a link. Links can be broken and the answer may get lost. I suggest you editing and include something like a simple example: this.Clients.GroupExcept("TheGroupName", yourExcludedConnectionIdsList);

Comment: Except, I did not just simply provide a link. I provided the name of what he should use and what it does to accomplish what he wants to do. The link is there to take to the documentation of the application, which could be easily replaced with a "go google that" statement but I don't like to take that approach.